# pointwise linear independence implies linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-independence

A set of vector valued function $y_i(t)$ is linear independent if
$$
c_1 y_1(t) + \cdots + c_n y_n(t) = 0 \quad 
\forall t \in \mathbb{R} 
\implies 
c_1 = c_2 = \cdots = c_n = 0. 
$$

Does this mean that pointwise linear independence of $y_i(t)$ implies linear independence? Since
\begin{align}
c_1 y_1(t) + \cdots + c_n y_n(t) = 0 \quad 
\forall t \in \mathbb{R} 
&\implies 
c_1 y_1(t_0) + \cdots + c_n y_n(t_0) = 0 \\
&\implies 
c_1 = c_2 = \cdots = c_n = 0. 
\end{align}

(I'm assuming $y_i(t)$ are pointwise linear independent at $t_0$.)

Comment: Yes, pointwise linear independence at $t_0$ is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the set of functions to be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to make sure since this reminded me of uniform convergence and pointwise convergence (where it is the other way around).

Comment: What is "*pointwise* linear independence"? What you wrote is linear independence as functions, in a vector space where functions are the points. To get a more localized version you need the combination to zero at at least $n$ different points simultaneously.